# Configuring Asp.NET Application in subfolder - Without IIS config

Tags: asp.net

I have a free hosting account, and two ASP.NET project.

I want to upload both apps in my hosting, like:
`www.hosting.com/myaccount/project1/`
`www.hosting.com/myaccount/project2/`

But the problem is when I run project1 or project2
Asp.net considers `application main path ("~")` as root `www.hosting.com/myaccount/`
Si I cant load dll, App_themes, and Other.
What can I do to stop that strange behvior!

I cant configure IIS because I am using free hosting.
I applied this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516041/run-an-asp-net-website-in-a-subfolder/2739203#2739203) and no thing happened.

Thank you for hepling.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an application at root that redirects to the other two.