# How to deploy web application to sub directory on MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, iis-8

When I deploy web application to sub directory on MVC site, i got this error.

**Compilation Error**

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How to resolve this problem ?

In my IIS: 
https://ibb.co/jp1iQa

My website with ASP.NET Web Application: 
https://ibb.co/dRYV5a

Thank.

Comment: it is little bit tricky, here is [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516041/run-an-asp-net-website-in-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

I need more information. Are you properly setting up a virtual host for this subdirectory? Does it work if it is in the root?

Sounds like you have a build issue, or perhaps you are deploying the source code and not the binary files.