# Manually deploying a simple ASP.NET Web Application (in a subfolder on port 81!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I can not believe I have to ask this, but here I am!

Here is all I have done:

1. Visual Studio 2013 - Create New ASP.NET Web Application (Empty).
   Saved it as MyWebApp.
2. Once the project was created, I right-clicked and added a new item: Web Form
   Saved it as index.aspx
3. In the designer, added a button.
4. Created a Click event for this button that looks like:

   ```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string myStringVariable = "foo";
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
   }
   ```

Done.  That's it.  Can't get any simpler.

So then I built it.  And published it using Visual Studio 2013.  I chose the Publish method of File System and a local location of C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

Now, I did this locally, in my VM, just to see what files it would place.  And as I thought, in wwwroot:

1. It created a bin folder and placed MyWebApp.dll in this folder.
2. It placed a web.config
3. It placed index.aspx.

So, now, let's go to my actual real web server!  I mean, I can place static html files there right now, and view them from my browser.  It works!

So I go to the default website (c:\inetpub\wwwroot), created a folder called ASP, and placed those files in it (index.aspx, web.config, bin folder with dll).

When I run it using (I'm on the server): http://localhost/ASP/index.aspx I continually get this parser error:

> Parser Error    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The file '/ASP/index.aspx.cs' does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebApp.index" %> Line 2:   Line
>   3:
>
> Source File:  /ASP/index.aspx    Line:  1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1086.0

(I have switched between CodeFile and CodeBehind - based on some googling here, neither works).

No matter what I do, I can't get index.aspx to "find/see" index.aspx.cs that's inside the dll.  Is there some configuration step I'm missing?  I just don't get it.

Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear, I believe it's because I put it in a subfolder.  It seems to work if I put those same files just in wwwroot, instead of the subfolder.  I just added that to the title, because as soon as I pressed submit on this question - I realized, maybe it's because it's in this subfolder!  Isn't that the way this always works?  Ask for help, and the process of writing it up gives you clarity? :)

EDIT: Arrgh!  The other tid-bit of info I left out was that I was trying this on Port 81.  I had created a 2nd Site (IIS) and binded it to port 81 (and yes I'm including that in my URL).  And I was playing around there.  And I had even thought to make it an Application (the subfolder).  But it just doesn't work there.  Only under my Default Web Site.  I must be missing some type of configuration information.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?  What's the .Net version on the app pool for the website?

Comment: See [Run an ASP.NET website in a subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516041/run-an-asp-net-website-in-a-subfolder).

Comment: this is a sign that the asp.net runtime attempts to compile from page source on startup. must be caused by either website/web application or codefile/codebehind. In your case, [CodeFile is wrong and CodeBehind would be correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/954873/1132334).

Comment: Well, it's the DefaultAppPool associated with DefaultWebSite.  So everything is as it was on install.  .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319.  Integrated pipeline mode.  The server is Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit).  I should be more clear that it seems to work when it's in the Default WebSite (wwwroot), but as I mentioned, I put it in a folder called ASP under wwwroot.

Comment: @dlatikay - I've tried both codefile and codebehind.  I think it's because I put it in a subfolder.  I'm about to check out Romoku's link

Comment: It's a combination of subfolder and being on port 81.  Did I not set up this IIS Site correctly?