# Adding Virtual directory under DNN website ,

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want to create virtual directory in my DNN website and make new database for this site ,  for this I go to  IIs manager and click  add virtual directory and browse that site it shows error

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Module    IIS Web Core Notification   BeginRequest
>
> Handler   Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x800700b7
>
> Config Error  Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with
>   unique key  attribute 'name' set to 'LogoffHandler*'
>
> Config File   \?\C:\Website\dnndev.me\web.config
>
> Requested URL http://www.dnndev.me:80/VirtualDnn Physical
>   Path  C:\Website\dnndev.me Logon Method   Not yet determined
>
> Logon User    Not yet determined Config Source   116:
>
> 117:
>
> 118:

Please tell me how can i resolve this problem ........

Thanks

Comment: have you follow the documnetaion of dnn . It clearly says that you have to give permissions to project folder with aspnet or networkservice. let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add

```
<location inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

To your web.config file so that DotNetNuke stops handling requests to that virtual directory.

Something along the lines of what is mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/782277/21362

An old blog post I wrote might also help

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/cid/135153/DotNetNuke-Tip-15-Running-a-webservice-inside-of-a-DNN-site.aspx