# error There is a duplicate 'entityFramework' section defined

Tags: entity-framework

I get this error :

```
Config Error       There is a duplicate 'entityFramework' section defined
Config File    \\?\D:\koopaproject\koopaproject\web.config
9: <!--For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468--> 
10:  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />11:   </configSections>
```

In my web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <!--For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468--> 
    <section name="entityFramework"   type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="koopaco.com_koopaContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial   Catalog=koopaco.com_koopa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=koopaco.com_zohre;Password=136613;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And I installed :

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

But I still get this error.

Comment: Did you check web.configs in parents folders or in machine.config that entity framework section is not specified?

Comment: what do you mean? it's web config in parent folder.and i did all things that i said above on it  .

Comment: What about config files in root directories?

    %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
    %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

Comment: i checked web.config and add Entity frame work section and assembly in machine.config but it did not change.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324333/there-is-a-duplicate-entityframework-section-defined-entityframework6-upgrad (currently #6 in the "Related" list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to web.config file

```
<entityFramework xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem.  The cause of my issue is that whilst I was running the application via IIS (as an application under the Default Web Site), there was a Web.config in the root that also had the `<entityFramework>` section defined.

Removed the Web.config from the root, and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem while testing in IIS Express, look for a conflict in the higher-level "web.config" used by IIS Express. I found that I had a problem in C:\Users\yourUserIDHere\Documents\IISExpress\config**applicationhost.config**.

applicationhost.config is a sort of higher-level web.config for IIS Express.

My site was defined in there with a left over folder location on my C: drive where I had run an older copy of my project in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to web.release.config file

```
<entityFramework xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
```

so that when you deploy the web application entityFramework will not be on the web app's config file