# Integrate 2 ASP.NET web applications within IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have 2 separately written ASP.NET web applications that I want to integrate within IIS7.
The first application A is the main site while application B is a subsite.
So application A is called from www.abc123.com and application B is called www.abc123.com/applicationB.

Within IIS7, I set up applicationB as a virtual directory with the file structure on a different path from the rest of the site.
However, when the URL www.abc123.com/applicationB is called it seems as if the web.config file of the main site is being executed. Since they are separately written sites, they do not have any knowledge of the other and errors occur looking for files, libraries etc.

What can I do to have IIS go directly to the subsite without looking at the web.config file of the main site?

Are there other possibilities? Please let me know if I can be more specific in asking this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic

Answer (score 1):

Convert `applicationB` into a Web Application Scope in IIS. Right-click on the Virtual Directory in the tree-view and select "Convert to Application", that will define a new application-scope which has its own web.config as the start of a new, separate, application.

This separate application will live in a separate AppDomain (or even a separate process, if you choose to run it in a different Application Pool). It will not share `Application` or `Session` state with applicationA, though it can share cookies as it's on the same domain.