# SubWebsite in Shared Server IIS 8.5

Tags: .net, iis, web

I have a shared server with IIS 8.5. its already running a website on like www.domain.com. I want to create a new website in visual studio 2012 and upload it on the server. the new website will not be directly uploaded to the root but a folder on root named subweb.

I want the sub website to access its own assemblies and have its own references. It should be accessible on the server with www.domain.com/subweb/default.aspx. I don't want to make any changes to the existing web project running on the root. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS Manager, right click on the folder just above where you'd like your sub-site to go and choose Add Application. If you want your sub-site to be found at /subsite/ then you'd be right clicking on the root of the main site and, after choosing Add Application, you'd need to provide a name and file path. Give your application a name of "subsite" (like with a virtual directory.) You'd then point to the physical file folder where you've published your new web site, which should be published to a different directory structure than your main site, rather than beneath it.

Comment: No problem. Your app itself should be fine but need to watch your sub-app's web.config though since it can inherit settings from the main one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic for some easy work-arounds you can apply to your sub-app's web.config.

Comment: its default web.config created for new webforms app. did not included anything extra