# MVC app as nested app of another MVC app, web.config issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a solution where our "root" site is an MVC application and our sub-sites will be nested applications under the root.  What I've found is that when we deploy the nested web application, I'm getting web.config errors from the root site.

Is possible to override the nested application to ignore the root configuration?

Comment: ...or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic also this may help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx