# Prevent inheriting parent web.config to child Application on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, iis, web-config

On **IIS 7.5** I have parent site using **parentAppPool** and SubApplication using **childAppPool**.

Parent site load all fine, but when I access subApplication as http://parentSite.com/SubApplication it is expecting DLLs from Parent site bin

In order to prevent the web.config inheritance, I tried wrapping `<system.web>` with `<location path="SubApplication" inheritInChildApplications="false">` and `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` this is breaking the parent site to work.

Then I tried adding  `enableConfigurationOverride="false"` attribute to **SubApplicationPool** in `applicationHost.config` that also didn't work

Any help would be appreciated.

**high level skeleton of web.config**
[image]

When I try this, I get Telerik error on parent site, but child site works!

> '~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config.
>   RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config.
>   Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or
>   see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `<location>` element I was able to disable the inheritance.

[image]
**But that raised new error with Telerik controls**

> '~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config.
>   RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config.
>   Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or
>   see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager

In order to solve that, I used **EnableHandlerDetection** attribute as mentioned in this [**Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptManager Documentation**](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/RadScriptManager)

> **EnableHandlerDetection** Boolean
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating if RadScriptManager should check the
>   Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource handler existence in the application
>   configuration file.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> When EnableHandlerDetection set to true, RadScriptManager
>   automatically checks if the HttpHandler it uses is registered to the
>   application configuration file and throws an exception if the
>   HttpHandler registration missing. Set this property to false if your
>   scenario uses a file to output the combined scripts, or when running
>   in Medium trust.

**Then I ended up with another error**

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been
>   detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

To resolve that I made the following changes to `<system.webserver>`

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    .... other stuff
   </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a specific configuration that you would like to be removed from the inheritance chain, you can use the `<clear/>` tag to remove any previous reference setting in the parent and you can start fresh.

The following example taken from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides) show how to remove previous memebership details and create a new one

```
 <membership>
   <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, 
                System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
                Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
          connectionStringName="MyDatabase"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          (additional elements removed for brevity)
       />
   </providers>
 </membership>
```

Comment: Well I would like to completely void the inheritance behavior here. How would i do that?

Comment: You are using `<location path="SubApplication" inheritInChildApplications="false">` Instead try `<location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false">` More [info](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc245724860)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic) as well

Comment: Do I have wrap that in parent web.config or child web.config?

Comment: Added it to system.web and system.webserver The configuration section 'location' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: I have updated my question. That helped to load the child site, but parent site is getting telerik error

Comment: the location path that you added above is it in parent web.config or child ?  My understanding was it has to be added in the parent web.config.

Comment: Yes in Parent web.config