# In iis webhosting I have wordpress as parent and CI as child

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, iis, iis-7

I have problem with my new hosting in iis I have wordpress in parent and codeigniter in child directory. My problem is that when I put wordpress web.config my codeigniter is not working and when I remove parent web.config there is another web.config in codeigniter directory which is working. In short at a time any one web app working related to their web.config. any solution??

Answer (score 0):

IIS will inherit config from parent directories. you can probably use the  tag inside the app config and connection string sections.

showing the actual configs would be helpful, do be sure to remove any credentials before sharing.

You may also find this [SO QA helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic) as it shows other ways to stop IIS inheritance.