# Umbraco nested applications or instances

Tags: iis, deployment, umbraco, umbraco7

Currently I am working on umbraco 7 and we need to add other umbraco instances under it.
let's take an example we have three umbraco instances.

1) http://example.com
2) http://example2.com
3) http://example3.com

now we wants something like below:

1) http://example.com
2) http://example.com/example2
3) http://example.com/example3

I have tried to create virtual directories and applications but we still face some issue and it's not working. some errors are mentioned below.

http://screencast.com/t/qzLloAm21qv

with application
http://screencast.com/t/gk7f17wB3TE
after commenting highlighted line
http://screencast.com/t/s7H9C3FpwXRS

Note: *I have also put example2 & example3 folders inside and outside of main instance directories*.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do that? You can easily have different sites (with entirely different templates and different URLs) in the same Umbraco instance - and if it's something to do with user management, you can use different start nodes for different users.

Comment: @JannikAnker on earth client have already developed and sites are live for around a year :)
Now he wants to merge different domains into a single domain without sub-domain as mentioned above.

Comment: Oh, alright then :-P To me it looks like some config inheritance mess, look here to see how you (might) fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/782252/3668031

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [reverse proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/) to handle this? Basically, you set up a "virtual folder" that is hosted on a different server.

I've not set one up myself, but [here is a good guide](http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2016/01/running-umbraco-over-reverse-proxy) that indicates that it's possible to do this with Umbraco.

Comment: Was going to suggest this (I wrote the blog post that you linked to). This gets round the issue of the nested config files, and seems to work much better than having it in a nested virtual directory. Depending on the complexity of the site, it can be quite fiddly to set up properly though.