# Can two ASP.NET applications share domain name on a single IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to elaborate some more on this question, but it is a straightforward one. Is it possible that two ASP.NET Web Api applications use the same domain ie. host name on a single IIS?

**app1**

- www.domain.com/api/users/ POST

**app2**

- www.domain.com/api/guests/ POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible yes, IIS supports multiple applications under a "parent".

Comment: could you explain your answer?

Comment: You can create a website in IIS for "www.domain.com/api" then whilst in IIS, right click and you will have the option "Add Application". For here you will be able to add both Applications.

Comment: are webconfigs shared in this case?

Comment: They will inherit from the parent config. However looking at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic it appears to be avoidable.