# ASP.NET web.confg avoid inheritance for configSections

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web-config, iis-7.5

Here is my parent site `web.config`:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="Duncan.PEMS.Web.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
.....
.....
.....
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
.....
.....
.....
```

My child site `web.config`:

```
<configSections>
    <remove name="entityFramework" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
.....
.....
.....
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="PemsUsProEntities" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

The problem here is that the parent site needs EF 5.0 and the child site needs EF 6.0. I want to know if I can override it on my child without touching anything on my parent site?

I tried `<remove name="entityFramework" />` in child `web.config` in configSections but it says

> Section or group name 'entityFramework' is already defined. Updates to
>   this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.

I am using IIS 7.5

Comment: you mean to say both the Sites are residing in same solution ?

Comment: Not solution. on IIS, I have site on IIS deployed from a solution-A, then I added application under that site, which is deployed from a different solution. Then it turned to be site under site, so parent site configs are conflicting with child site.

Comment: Have you looked at "location" settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx

Comment: This question is answered in another link in overflow [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic)

Comment: That doesn't explain about config section. And I tried that on config section which did not work