# Web Deploy - two similar apps 1 works 1 doesn't despite successful deploy reported

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy, iis-8.5

I've got a Windows 2012 r2 server with IIS 8.5 running on it.

I am trying to deploy a new web app in a sub folder of the root website. This is my third web app that I will have up there and the prior two are fine, but for some reason this app when I use Web Deploy to push it doesn't fully populate all of the Features for the app.

I had to manually enter Application Settings and Session State is completely greyed out so I can't even fill in what exists on the other web apps I've published.

Recently I upgraded to VS 2017 so I thought it might be a glitch in my setup so I ripped one of the two existing apps out and did a re-deploy on them and they work perfectly.

I'd post more info but I am not sure what someone helping might want to see.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Updated: May Monday 15th,7:50AM Central US --

I went back and looked at the Features view and compared the content from the working app (republished as a test and still worked fine) and this one that I'm having the difficulty with. Here are the results. (this with 100% success reported in Web Deployment publish)

I am able to edit the first two of these feature items to make them identical to the working app but not the third.  All options on this are grayed out:
[image]

Comment: check the user your site and app pool are running as.  Are the other two running as virtual directories?  Did all your files make it to the server?

Comment: @RandomUs1r, App pools are fine, I've checked them several times. When I publish using the Web Deployment tool all files are reporting successful transfer without errors.  As a cross check I have republished another app on the same site and it works perfectly.  I've even gone to the effort of comparing the feature sets of the working app and the one that I'm trying to get running. This indicated differences in the .NET Authorization Rules, Application Settings, and Session State. While I can modify the first two of these. Session State I can not.

Comment: Are all the apps the same .net version? Do you have the correct .net version installed for each app?  Also, under basic settings in IIS I believe you can see who the app is running as (this is separate from app pool), might be worth looking at that.  Lastly, do you still have VS 2015 somewhere? I'd try deploying using that to rule out any VS 2017 issues.

Comment: Yes, both are using .NET 4.6.1.  The only thing really different in the development of each app was the first one that has been in production for some time now was developed entirely under VS2015, while this new one was developed using VS2017.    

However the republish of the first web app was accomplished using VS2017 web deploy just as I am trying to do with the newer one. I did this to see if there was a problem with the Web Deploy tool in VS2017. The republish resulted in the original app working as it had deployed under VS2015 IDE.

Comment: can you deploy the new solution to localhost? Also, reading your error, your web.config might have two session provider sections, might be worth looking at the actual content of the web.config as that's what IIS reads off of to adjust some of its settings.

Comment: I've managed to get the app working but the problem now is that what I had to do to get it to work is butcher my web.config in the root web folder. This blows up my menu page that I use to launch the web apps from.  How do I go about telling IIS to disregard the content in the /web.config?  The /VulTrack/web.config is what it should be using.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782252/avoid-web-config-inheritance-in-child-web-application-using-inheritinchildapplic .  If there's conflicting sections between the virtual directories & the root web.config (you probably need the root as it runs your root app / menu), you can use the syntax in the link to tell the web.configs which sections to use / inherit.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I read through that thread and the section by section process wasn't working because of my 'runtime' section. Every time I tried to apply the inheritInChildApplications="false" to that section it would blow up. Then I saw another answer down further that suggests creating a new app pool and adding enableConfigurationOverride="false" the app pool by editing %WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config.  Works perfectly!

Comment: RandomUs1r, I'd love to give you credit for this answer, but need you to document a response as an answer so I can mark it as the solution. You deserve credit for it as you've worked with me through this and I really appreciate the assistance.